# Disabling operators overloads if a given template is not specialized for the operator parameters type

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

I'm writting a metaprogramming library which includes a set of compile-time arithmetic types and functions. For example:

**metafunctions.hpp**

```
template<typename T>
struct function
{
    using result = T;
};

template<typename LHS , typename RHS>
struct add_t;

//Add metafunction
template<typename LHS , typename RHS>
using add = typename add_t<LHS,RHS>::result;
```

**fixed_point.hpp**:

```
#include "metafunctions.hpp"

template<long long int BITS , unsigned int PRECISSION>
struct fixed_point
{
    operator float()
    {
        return (float)BITS * std::pow(10.0f,-(float)PRECISION); //Its implemented as decimal fixed_point, not binary.
    };
};

//An alias which provides a convenient way to create numbers: scientific notation
template<int mantissa , int exponent = 0 , fbcount PRECISSION = mpl::DEFAULT_FRACTIONAL_PRECISION> // MANTISSA x 10^EXPONENT
using decimal = mpl::fixed_point<decimal_shift<mantissa , PRECISSION + exponent>::value , PRECISSION>; 

//add specialization:
template<long long int BITS1 , long long int BITS2 , unsigned int PRECISSION>
struct add_t<mpl::fixed_point<BITS1,PRECISION> , mpl::fixed_point<BITS2,PRECISION>> : public mpl::function<fixed_point<BITS1+BITS2 , PRECISION>> {};
```

A few days ago I have noticed that I could take advantage of `decltype` keyword and implement [expression templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates) to simplify the syntax of complex expressions:

**expressions.hpp**

```
template<typename LHS , typename RHS>
mpl::add<LHS,RHS> operator+(const LHS& , const RHS&);

template<typename LHS , typename RHS>
mpl::sub<LHS,RHS> operator-(const LHS& , const RHS&);

template<typename LHS , typename RHS>
mpl::mul<LHS,RHS> operator*(const LHS& , const RHS&);

template<typename LHS , typename RHS>
mpl::div<LHS,RHS> operator/(const LHS& , const RHS&);
```

*An example of its usage:*

```
using pi = mpl::decimal<3141592,-6>; //3141592x10⁻-6 (3,141592)
using r  = mpl::decimal<2,-2>; //0,002
using a  = mpl::decimal<1>; // 1,0 

using x = decltype( pi() * r() + ( r() / a() ) ); //pi*r + (r/a)
```

But this has a downside: **That overloads are defined for any type**, so expressions like `"a string" + "other string"` fits in the `expressions.hpp` `operator+` overload. Of course that overload resolution results in a compilation error, because the compiler is trying to fit `std::string` as type parameters of `mpl::add_t`.

My question is: **Is there any way to disable/enable the overloads (with `std::enable_if` or  something like that) based on the existence of a specialization of an specific template (`mpl::add_t` in the example) for the parameters of the functions/operators?**.

So if the result type of the expression has an specialization for the types of the parameters, the operator will be enabled, and disabled in other case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
template<typename LHS , typename RHS>
typename std::enable_if<
   !std::is_same<
       void,
       typename mpl::add_t<LHS,RHS>::result
    >::value,
    mpl::add<LHS,RHS>
>::type
operator+(const LHS& , const RHS&)
{
    // ...
}
```

relying on the fact that if and only if there is a specialization, a typedef `add_t<LHS,RHS>::result` exists (and which is not `void`).

Comment: And what about using that with the template alias, `mpl::add<LHS,RHS> = typename mpl::add_t<LHS,RHS>::result`, that would work? Or the compiler rejects it when instantiates the alias?

Comment: @Manu343726: Frankly, I don't know. Try it out, you have code ready to test it :)

Comment: Ok, I will try it later. Even if that case doesn't work, that looks like the correct answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: note that an empty default `template` can make SFINAE work better.  Otherwise it is not found, instead of empty.